# Google my business - API to update opening hours of places?

Tags: google-api, google-places-api

I would like to update "Opening hours" for all stores of a company in Google my business, through an automated API (a REST service for example).

My customer has hundreds of stores, and currently this is done manually.

I've read there is NO automated way to do this, a user needs to fill manually every opening hour in the google my business portal.

I can't believe that, and I'm wondering how big companies with a lot of stores take care of that problem, especially for "exceptional closings", etc.
I have already search for a long, and didn't found anything.

The only ability supplied by google is to upload a list of stores, through a file, and this file doesn't contain any information regarding opening hours (am I wrong ?).
I would like to be able to update store list AND opening hours regularly, through an API (My Business, or Places).

Does google propose a such API, or do you have any suggestion to handle this concern from a programmatical point of view ?

Thank you

Comment: It is possible now at https://developers.google.com/my-business/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There was no Google API for My Business at the time when I posted my question, but meanwhile Google has released it and also provides samples for many languages : https://developers.google.com/my-business/
Thanks to eton_ceb for the notification.